# React Native WebView content not resizing

Tags: android, webview, react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to the react native world and in developing an app I have come across an issue that I cannot seem to resolve with React-Native's webview component. When render a html page the content that gets loaded it larger than the viewport in both the simulator and actual device. I have followed the documentation on React-Native's site (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html), along with trying to use google to find answers to the issue and I cannot seem to find a solid solution. Below is an image of what the viewport is rendering currently.
[Current View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4MJJ.png)

Can someone please provide me some help regarding this issue? I don't know what else I need to do solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following:

`<WebView
....
scalesPageToFit={true}
/>`

The documentation states it is set to 'true' by default but when I added "scalesPageToFit" it solved the issue.